# Getting weird error installing Burg

Tags: command-line, dual-boot, grub2, bootloader, burg

I tried installing Burg to make my dual boot look better. So, I followed [these](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-make-your-dual-boot-better-with-burg) instructions up to the part where it says: "BURG found! Do you want to configure BURG instead of grub2?, click Yes.". Then I get this weird error:

```
burg-mkconfig couldn't be executed successfully. error message:
 Generating burg.cfg ...
/usr/sbin/burg-probe: error: cannot stat `/boot/burg/locale'.
No path or device is specified.
Try `/usr/sbin/burg-probe --help' for more information.
```

I don't really now how to use the terminal, so when I copy-pasted it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> nothing happened. When I clicked on the button "Environment settings", everything seems fine, except for the `OUTPUT_DIR`. Next to it is a warning sign and in the textfield there is: `/boot/burg/burg.cfg`.So apparently something isn't how it's supposed to be.

Does anyone know what I did wrong?

Suggested edit:

I ran this command :

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:n-muench/burg -y && sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer -y && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install burg burg-themes grub-customizer
```

As far as I can remember no errors appeared. I run a BIOS system.

Edit 2: Another user suggested I'd run the command `biosdecode`. Here's the output:

```
BIOS32 Service Directory present.
    Revision: 0
    Calling Interface Address: 0x000F0010
PCI Interrupt Routing 1.0 present.
    Router ID: 00:1f.0
    Exclusive IRQs: None
    Compatible Router: 8086:3a16
    Slot Entry 1: ID 00:00, on-board
    Slot Entry 2: ID 00:04, on-board
    Slot Entry 3: ID 00:05, on-board
    Slot Entry 4: ID 00:06, on-board
    Slot Entry 5: ID 00:08, on-board
    Slot Entry 6: ID 00:09, on-board
    Slot Entry 7: ID 00:0a, on-board
    Slot Entry 8: ID 00:0d, on-board
    Slot Entry 9: ID 00:16, on-board
    Slot Entry 10: ID 00:1f, on-board
    Slot Entry 11: ID 00:1d, on-board
    Slot Entry 12: ID 00:1a, on-board
    Slot Entry 13: ID 00:1b, on-board
    Slot Entry 14: ID 00:1c, on-board
    Slot Entry 15: ID 07:00, slot number 32
    Slot Entry 16: ID 05:00, slot number 37
    Slot Entry 17: ID 00:01, on-board
    Slot Entry 18: ID 00:02, on-board
    Slot Entry 19: ID 00:03, on-board
    Slot Entry 20: ID 03:00, slot number 2
    Slot Entry 21: ID 00:07, on-board
    Slot Entry 22: ID 04:00, slot number 5
    Slot Entry 23: ID 08:00, slot number 3
    Slot Entry 24: ID 08:01, slot number 4
    Slot Entry 25: ID 00:19, on-board
    Slot Entry 26: ID 06:00, on-board
    Slot Entry 27: ID 02:00, on-board
    Slot Entry 28: ID 08:02, on-board
    Slot Entry 29: ID 01:00, on-board
PNP BIOS 1.0 present.
    Event Notification: Not Supported
    Real Mode 16-bit Code Address: F000:67D2
    Real Mode 16-bit Data Address: F000:0000
    16-bit Protected Mode Code Address: 0x000F67FA
    16-bit Protected Mode Data Address: 0x000F0000
ACPI 1.0 present.
    OEM Identifier: ACPIAM
    RSD Table 32-bit Address: 0xBF780000
SMBIOS 2.5 present.
    Structure Table Length: 3002 bytes
    Structure Table Address: 0x000F0700
    Number Of Structures: 79
    Maximum Structure Size: 189 bytes
`
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the *exact* commands you ran and the output they produced instead of linking to the guide. Also explain what you pasted into the terminal (if it was a command, you need to hit enter for it to do anything). Finally, tell us whether this is a BIOS or EFI system (show us the output of `ls -ld /sys/firmware/efi`).

Comment: I know I have a BIOS system, but if I run this command I get the message: "cannot access '/sys/firmare/efi': No such file or directory". Don't be mad if I did something wrong because I don't know much about the terminal.

Comment: @imRobert7 : BIOS and (U)EFI are two completely different things. You can only have one of them, not both at the time. EFI is like an evolution of BIOS. If you are sure it's BIOS, run this command:  `biosdecode`and add output to your question.

Comment: Added it, but I wonder how this would help me?